# How to create routes for a controller function which needs argument in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I want to know how can I create routes for a controller function which needs an argument to be passed.
Like if I create a function like this:

```
function abc($arg)
 {
     return $arg;
 }
```

Then how can I specify a route for the same function? My argument will be containing a mixture of alphabets and numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your **APP_PATH/application/config/routes.php**

```
$route['controller_name/abc/([A-Za-z0-9])+'] = "controller_name/abc/$1";
```

for more details http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: I got it. Instead of ([a-z]*\d*)+ i used (:any) and it worked. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

use the [uri class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) and try reading the segments passed to your method

in the controller method below you pass the url segments such as 
controller / function / argument1 / argument2 / argument3 / 4 / 5 / 6 / ..

```
// controller
public function myfunction(){
 var_dump($this->url->segment(1)); // route/abc -> abc
 var_dump($this->url->segment(2)); // route/abc/123 -> 123
}
```

if the function take fixed length of parameters then something like

```
public function myfunction($arg1,$arg2){
 // ..
}
```

you can work the route mapping to make this work,

```
$route["myfunction/(any)"= "remap" // ..
```